# Find the starting and ending sector of the partitions?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8

Is there any built in tool in Windows to find the starting and ending sector of the partitions?

Answer (score 1):

you can get a live cd of Gparted to view detailed partition information that will show more information than what is shown in the above comment.

Alternatively, you can boot practically any live cd version of linux (without needing to install linux) and run the following command:

```
# for i in /dev/sd[a-z];do parted $i unit s print; done
```

What the above will do is iterate a bash loop to show you the partitioning schema of all connected hard disks to your system. It is likely (as this is disk 0) that it will be /dev/sda, but that is not always a guarantee. That command will actually provide quite verbose output as seen below:

```
for i in /dev/sd[a-z];do parted $i unit s print; done
Model: Areca killerofsoulsR1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 11721085440s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start         End           Size         File system     Name  Flags
 3      2048s         2097154047s   2097152000s  ntfs                  msftdata
 6      2097154048s   7051321343s   4954167296s                        lvm
 2      7051321344s   9619738623s   2568417280s                  lvm   lvm
 1      9619738624s   11716890623s  2097152000s                        lvm
 5      11716890624s  11721084927s  4194304s     linux-swap(v1)

Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500118192s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start       End         Size        File system  Name       Flags
 2      2048s       116002815s  116000768s  ntfs         SSD_GAMES  msftdata
 1      116002816s  220067839s  104065024s                          lvm
 3      220067840s  220600319s  532480s     fat32        EFI        boot, esp
 5      220600320s  500117503s  279517184s  ntfs                    msftdata
```

As you can see, that gives start and end sectors as well as size, filesystem type, partition name, and flags. It will also tell you what type of partitioning table you're using and sector sizes.

You can also execute this without the "unit s" portion if you want sizes in human readable formats such as GB and TB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell (as administrator) to get basic offset and partition size information.
the specific command is

> Get-Partition

read more about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848682.aspx) but a basic usage would be:

Run Powershell as administrator:

> On the Start screen, type PowerShell, right-click the Windows
>   PowerShell app tile, and then, in the app bar, click Run as
>   administrator.

[image]